# 2 different values for contextCSN in OpenLDAP

Tags: openldap

I have a 2-Way Multi-Master Mirror Mode OpenLDAP (v2.4) cluster.
While troubleshooting sync problems, I noticed the `dn: cn=config` entry has 2 different `contextCSN` values. After re-reading the [documentation](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/replication.html) this appears broken to me.

```
contextCSN: 20171211185042.240768Z#000000#001#000000
contextCSN: 20171025210324.456975Z#000000#002#000000
```

Is this normal, acceptable, broken, ???

Is the 001 and 002 in them related to `rid=1` and `rid=2` in the syncrepl config of `dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config`?

Answer (score 1):

is acceptable, because you must have a contextCSN: for each ldap provider you replicate the configuration, each contextCSN: reference to an ldap